# General Guidance on Cloudformation for Redshift, RDS, S3, EC2/Autoscaling etc

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I'm planning to create Redshift Cluster that will talk to RDS, S3, (SQS Workernodes with ASG. What are the industry norms for creating cfn template. Are all the resources put together in one stack or broken down into multiple stacks and nest them together? Redshift will feed data both direction RDS and S3. Any pointer to sample templates?

Comment: before considering the cf template, you need to decide your architecture and especially data flows.

Comment: I do have a dataflow architecture in place already. Inclining to use Lambda for S3-SQS Processing.